# How to get rid of grid on map

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to remove the grid from behind my map. Is there a way to change the background to white so there is no grid?

```
# Plot
us = map_data("state")
religiosity = religiosity %>% mutate(State = tolower(State))
us_rel = merge(us, religiosity, by.x = "region", by.y = "State")
p1 = ggplot(us_rel, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = Rank)) +
geom_polygon() +
theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(),              axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
    axis.title.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(),                    axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) +
scale_fill_gradient(low = "azure3", high = "deeppink4") +
labs(title = "Religiosity by State", fill = "Rank")
p1

# Interactive Plot
```

ip1 = ggplotly(p1)
ip1

Comment: This isn't a reproducible example, at least for me (`religiosity` isn't defined), but in general `theme_classic()` would get you a plot on a white background, no grid.

Comment: how to modify ggplot appearance: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html